# Which is the best way to generate unique serial number?

Tags: c#, licensing

I develop an application that needs to have a licence. It should be unique per machine. In the earlier versions I used Windows serial number for this purpose: i read it from Win, made some tricks/encryption on it to generete serial number & lic file. It was my own solution, in my new project I'd like to make a new one.

My question is:
Is there a widely used way to generate unique serial numbers? Any, which is based on some hardware serial number, like motherboard or processor etc.?

(.Net4/C#/VS2010)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would generating GUIDs not do the job? These should be unique (for practical purposes anyway) or is there a specific requirement for attaching it to the machine in question?

Comment: Try look here: [Generating Unique Key (Finger Print) for a Computer for Licensing Purposes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GenerateUniqueKey.aspx)

Comment: Depends on how you are going to check your key.  If you are doing a one-time creation then a GUID would be the way to go, but it sounds like you want to be able to check it (at least I assume you do since you talk about h/w serial numbers) to ensure software is only running on a particular machine... If that's the case, a GUID wouldn't server your needs.

Comment: GUID is not an option, it should be used on a particular PC. Checking would be based on this at every startup.

Answer (score 0):

[GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx).

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx) to understand the options you have in Guid's `ToString()`

Comment: Using a GUID is fine if you only need to do a one-shot creation of a key.  If you need it to be repeatable (say you want to check the authenticity of it on a given machine by re-creating the key and comparing) you're going to be out of luck.

Comment: Thx, GUID is not an option for me for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

using guid?

GUIDs can be created in a number of ways, but usually they are a combination of a few unique settings based on specific point in time (e.g., an IP address, network MAC address, clock date/time, etc.).